# Is there a way to optimize recursive query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursive-query

I have this query which creates two copies of the same table (the original table doesn't have an unique id) so I used `row_number` to order the tables:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Policy ASC) AS RowNumber, * 
INTO Example1 
FROM Payments

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Policy ASC) AS RowNumber, * 
INTO Example2
FROM Payments
```

And I want to check if the value in 'Import' it's the same as the value in 'Import' from the row before the actual one from my table ordered by policy.

I did a comparison with my two tables using the row number to check the values before the actual and if both of them are equals it set the column 'Review' as checked which means Import its the same as the Import from the row before the actual value.

Here's what I did, but it takes a LOOOONG time to execute... So I was wondering if I can optimize this query or do what i want on a different way?

```
DECLARE @intCount INT
SELECT @intCount = COUNT(DISTINCT(RowNumber)) FROM Example1   

DECLARE @i int  
SET @i = 1  

WHILE @i <= @intCount  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @Import decimal(15,2)  

    SELECT @Import = Import 
    FROM Example1 
    WHERE RowNumber = @i

    DECLARE @RowNumberBefore bigint

    SELECT @RowNumberBefore = RowNumber 
    FROM Example1 
    WHERE RowNumber = @i - 1 

    UPDATE TOP (1) Example1  
    SET Review = 'Checked'
    FROM Example1 a 
    JOIN Example2 b ON a.Policy = b.Policy  
    WHERE a.Import = @Import 
      AND a.RowNumber = @RowNumberBefore

    SET @i = @i + 1  
END
```

Example of desired result:

If I have this :

```
RowNumber     Policy    Import   Review
---------     ------    ------   ------
1             0001      586.45
2             0002      586.45
3             0003       65.50
4             0004      249.30
5             0005       65.50
6             0005      153.35
7             0006       32.50
8             0006       32.50
9             0007       32.50
10            0009      250.00
```

I want to update review with 'checked' if import its the same as the import before the actual one (i can't use policy as id since it can has duplicate values).

So, if I have values ordered by policy (with rowcount) I'm using `rowNumber` to compare 'Policy' in the order I want to:

```
RowNumber     Policy    Import   Review
---------     ------    ------   ------
1             0001      586.45   Checked
2             0002      586.45   Checked
3             0003       65.50
4             0004      249.30
5             0005       65.50
6             0005      153.35
7             0006       32.50   Checked
8             0006       32.50   Checked
9             0007       32.50   Checked
10            0009      250.00
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  As a note:  if `policy` has duplicates, then `row_number()` can produce different results.  Also, what is "Import"?  You mention it in the text but it doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: Depending on how many rows are involved (bigint? really?), creating indexes on the `Example` tables would make a massive difference. (As would writing SQL code, as per all the answers you will get to this question.)

Comment: Import is a numeric value, that i want to compare if it's the same as the row before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one query using `LAG()` to get the previous row value, something like this:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Import = LAG(Import) over (ORDER BY Policy)
               THEN 'Checked'
               ELSE 'Whatever'
          END Review
INTO Example1
FROM Payments
```

SQL Server 2008 and prior will use logic similar to your approach, but do it at a table level instead of row.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT p.*, CASE WHEN p.Import = p2.Import
                 THEN 'Checked'
                 ELSE 'Whatever'
            END as Review
INTO Example1
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY policy) RN
      FROM Payment) p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Import, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY policy) RN
           FROM Payment) p2 on p.RN = p2.RN - 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't use LAG, since I'm using SQL Server 2008. There's a similar function for this version?

Comment: @Legendarkz I added a 2008 solution, not sure if it is more or less performant than Gordon's.  The `INTO` is optional of course.

Answer (score 2):

> And I want to check if the value in 'Import' it's the same as the value in 'Import' from the row before the actual one from my table ordered by policy.

I don't see what `row_number()` or `update` has to do with this question.  If you want to identify the rows where `import` changes, then how about this:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             lag(p.import) over (order by p.policy) as prev_import
      from payments p
     ) p
where prev_import <> import;
```

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you would just use `outer apply` instead:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, p2.import as prev_import
      from payments p outer apply
           (select top 1 p2.*
            from payments p2
            where p2.policy < p.policy
            order by p2.policy desc
           ) p2
     ) p
where prev_import <> import;
```

Performance will still be pretty bad, but an index on `payments(policy, import)` would help.

Answer (score 0):

First there is no need to create two versions with row_number. You can join to the same table.

```
SELECT Payment.Policy, Payment.Import, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY policy) RN
    INTO #temp
FROM Payment
```

If your table is large, you can now add an index to it. Note I only used the columns I need. Then the query is

```
SELECT t.Import,t.policy,  CASE WHEN t.Import = t2.Import
                 THEN 'Checked'
                 ELSE 'Whatever'
            END as Review
FROM #Temp t
LEFT JOIN #Temp t2 on t.RN = t2.RN - 1
```

If you actually want to update the original table, then you have a further issue because you do not have a unique identifier in the table. So what do you join to? Further I can see some problems with your data because you have ordered on policy but have multiple records with policy.  Suppose you had this data:

```
RowNumber     Policy    Import   Review
---------     ------    ------   ------
1             0001      586.45
2             0002      586.45
3             0003       65.50
4             0004      249.30
5             0005       65.50
6             0005      249.30
7             0006       32.50
8             0006       32.50
9             0007       32.50
10            0009      250.00
```

Now maybe the value for Review in Policy 0004 and 0005 would depend on the way it chose to handle the two 0005 records. One would be a match but the other would not and you have nothing to guarantee the order of those 005 records. This whole issue is a classic case of why you should not create a table without a primary key.

Comment: I know it's a bad practice, but I didn't make that table. That's why I used row_count as a solution for this problem ordering by Policy (which is how it's ordered), but I do agree with you that I don't need two tables, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: That alone shoudl save some processing time as well as the indexing of teh temp table is the table is large